# Ubuntu 20.04 network interfaces

Tags: networking, 20.04, configuration, netplan

Is there any way to change configuration of IP address like in old distribution like 17.10 and 11.04.
For example I've changed Ip address in /etc/network/interfaces but in 20.04 it's impossible to do this way and netplan is not easy to use.

Comment: Netplan is the future. If you have a netplan YAML file, add it to your question so we can help you fix it. If you are banging your head trying to make your first netplan YAML file, add your old interfaces file to the question so we can help you translate it. The first time for either way is hard. Having done both, I find netplan easier.

Comment: Maybe it is future but I saw that it is possible to modify and then everything works like in old version for me is much better. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, things change and systemd has taken control over many parts of linux. If you wnat a static ip for your device create a file with sudo:

```
/etc/systemd/network/myconnection.network

[Match]
Name=enp0s25 #check your interfaces for this name

[Network]
DNS=10.10.0.3 #DNS, it may be like the gateway
Address=10.10.0.10/24 #the ip address of your device
Gateway=10.10.0.1  #your router
```

I've commented the entries (I assumed that your local gateway is 10.10.0.1 - you must use yours of course)

That done the systemd service has to be enabled:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
systemctl start systemd-networkd
```

Now you are set. The "enabled" keyword ensures, that the service will be started after a reboot, the "start" does it (once) immediately

You can check if everthing works with `networkctl status enp0s25`whereas your netwrok device may differ. The name of your device can be checked with:

`ip a`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: if my answer helped, you could accept it ;-)

Comment: Not recommended to do this directly in systemd config.  The recommended way to do this is with netplan.

Comment: I found what I looking for but thanks everyone for help ) :
1.
sudo apt update
2.
sudo apt install ifupdown net-tools

3.
nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"

4.
sudo update-grub

5.
nano /etc/network/interface

6.
sudo ifdown --force eth0
7.
sudo ifup eth0

8.
ifconfig 

9.
sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf 
10.
sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf lub po prostu kasujemy rm i tworzymy nowy plik resolv.conf

11.
sudo dpkg -P cloud-init
12.
sudo rm -fr /etc/cloud/

13.
sudo systemctl disable --now systemd-resolved

Comment: @slangasek: how so? Is that an official position? On the face of it, netplan is completely unnecessary. My 22.04 server VMs use systemd-networkd exclusively. Besides, this is an excellent way to recover from unexpected problems: uninstalling `cloud-init`, for example, which removes dhcp and netplan.